# The progress bar does not show download update. It keeps showing 0%

Tags: android

In this android code to download a file from server, the progress bar is displayed but it does not show any update. It always shows only 0%. How to make it show the update? Kindly help.

```
public class download extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload();
        }
    });
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}
}
}
```

Comment: In Logs which value showing for ANDRO_ASYNC ?

Comment: Yeah, check your logs. Your code looks OK. Maybe it's just downloading and dismissing too quickly for you to notice the progress change.

Comment: ANDRO_ASYNC value in log is 611202 @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: I checked my log. The ANDRO_ASYNC value is 611202. What should i do to make the progress bar show update?@MikeM.

Comment: Are you seeing the log print in `onProgressUpdate()` - `Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);`? If not, then you've probably got some Exception thrown in the `try`, but you're ignoring it in the `catch`. Add `e.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` block, and see what you get in the logs.

Comment: did you sure your image is present in this url = "http://farm1.static.flickr.com/114/298125983_0e4bf66782_b.jpg";   

becouse i hit your url but not found image there

Comment: Image is present @sushantgosavi